# Create Populate, Then Delete a Table from Within a View (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view that compares the data in two tables (tableYesterday and tableToday) and outputs a result based on the comparison. Lets call this view: ViewComp.

I have a need to do more than this. WIthin a single view, I actually need to:

1. create or replace `tableToday` and pre-populate it.
2. execute the `ViewComp` query.
3. replace `tableYesterday` with `tableToday`.

I have researched things like nested views but I could not find a way to perform 1 and 3 from within the view. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a bad idea.  Views shouldn't "do" anything.

For those extremely rare cases where this is required, it can be done with the tricks below.  You will definitely want to document this code, to explain to other people what you're doing and why.

**Sample schema and objects**

```
--Create table.
create table tableYesterday(a number, b number);

--Create abstract data type to hold one row of data to be returned by the view.
create or replace type ViewComp_type is object
(
    a number,
    b number
);

--Create nested table to hold multiple rows of data to be returned by the view.
create or replace type ViewComp_nt is table of ViewComp_type;
```

**Function to return results**

```
--Create function to return data.
create or replace function ViewComp_function return ViewComp_nt authid current_user as
    --This pragma is necessary for a function that will perform DML.
    pragma autonomous_transaction;

    v_results ViewComp_nt;

    v_name_already_exists exception;
    pragma exception_init(v_name_already_exists, -955);
begin
    --Try to create today's table.  Ignore errors if it exists.
    begin
        execute immediate 'create table tableToday(a number, b number)';
    exception when v_name_already_exists then
        execute immediate 'truncate table tableToday';
    end;

    --Populate today's table.
    execute immediate 'insert into tableToday values(1,1)';

    --Get the difference.
    execute immediate q'[
        select cast(collect(ViewComp_type(a,b)) as ViewComp_nt)
        from
        (
            select * from tableToday
            minus
            select * from tableYesterday
        )
    ]' into v_results;

    --Remove yesterday's data.
    execute immediate 'truncate table tableYesterday';

    --Replace it with today's data.
    execute immediate 'insert into tableYesterday select * from tableToday';
    commit;

    --Return the difference.
    return v_results;
end;
/
```

**Create the view to return the function's data**

```
create or replace view ViewComp as
select * from table(ViewComp_function);
```

**Test Run**

```
--First execution:
select * from ViewComp;

A   B
-   -
1   1

--Second execution:
select * from ViewComp;

A   B
-   -
```

Comment: thanks Jon! I have created the components above and executed the view. It works precisely as you described. At this time, I am going to take a moment or two to make sure I fully comprehend what you did. I will probably have follow-up questions soon. Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: Hmm, I am getting a runtime error when executing the above code with the modifications I needed for my situation. I have included my code hoping you might be able to help (see my edits to this question for the code). Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: by the way, the error I am getting is
"ORA-00911: invalid character", and it is in the area of: 
    execute immediate q'[
   select cast(collect(PRESIDENTCOMP_TYPE(flag, ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)) as PRESIDENTCOMP_NT)

Comment: @TimClotworthy You need to remove the semicolon at the end of this line: `order by ID;`.

Comment: thanks that was it. I wanted to ask you whether there is a way to use the existing types rather than the explicit create statement: execute immediate 'create table tableToday(a number, b number)'; For instance, I tried: DECLARE @ Table AS viewComp_nt

SELECT *
INTO dbo.NewTable
FROM @ Table
WHERE 1 = 2, but it did not work. thanks again!

Comment: @TimClotworthy I'm not sure if I understand.  Could you modify the question?

Comment: ok, originally, you created function:ViewComp_function. Inside the function, we created table: tableToday, using statement: execute immediate 'create table tableToday(a number, b number)'; That worked, but am looking for way to reuse existing user defined type:ViewComp_type to create tableToday rather than redefining the structure tableToday(a number, b number). I tried DECLARE TYPE tmpToday IS TABLE OF ViewComp_type (creating  table variable) and then used execute immediate 'SELECT *
INTO tableToday FROM @ tmpToday WHERE 1 = 2' to create tableToday, but it didn't even compile.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused on what you're trying to do.  It's unusual to create and use a table inside PL/SQL.  If you really need a table for processing you should just keep it in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such things in view. You can either create PL/SQL procedure to perform your steps or create materialised view.